# Change default Blender render output format?

Tags: file-format

Does anyone know if there's any way to change Blender's default render output format for saving? I prefer to save my renders as OpenEXR files, but Blender insists on keeping PNG as the default, forcing me to manually change it each time I save.

Comment: Hello, in a default file, you can change the setting and save the modified file as the default starting file, would this work ?

Comment: @Gorgious You should enter this as answer and maybe show him how he changes the startup file, so he can accept this answer.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann suggested as a duplicate rather, it's a common q/a :)

Comment: @Gorgious I guess you're right, I think I'll vote for Close, too.